# Why isn't `src` changing when I change it from the function?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, pass-by-value

My program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

char* str(char*src);\\declared as function global
main()
{
    char src[40]="hello";
    clrscr();
    puts(src);
    str(src);\\ function called
    puts(src);\\does not put changed string?
    getch();
    return 0;
}

char* str( char *src)
{
    src="readers";\\changing my source string<--is it changes???
    return src;\\returning source sting
}
```

output:

> ```
> hello
> hello
> ```

Why is `src` not becoming `"readers"`?

Comment: `return src;` doesn't have an effect in the code you've provided. And one question at a time please! FYI, there aren't any function pointers in the code snippet

Comment: This would be less confusing if you used a different name for the function parameter than for the array in `main`.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `src="readers";` is wrong. You have to try like

```
strcpy(src, "readers");
```

The reason is, `C` uses pass by value while passing function parameters. So, `src` here is passed by value, so you cannot change `src` from inside the function. You can change `*src` from the function. So, to change the content pointed by `src`, you have to use `strcpy()`.

Also, as Mr, **@coolguy** has mentioned, you're not using the return value of `str()`, so the `return` statement is making no impact here.

Answer (score 2):

Inside main you declared array

```
char src[40]="hello";
```

When you pass the array to the function

```
str(src);
```

it is converted to a temporary object that is a pointer to the first element of the array. The parameter of the function is a local variable of the function that is destroyed after exiting the function.

You can imagine the function call and its definition the following way

```
str(src);

char* str( void )
{
    char * s = &src[0]
    s = "readers";

    return s;
}
```

That is at first this local variable (I renamed it like s that to distinguish it from the original array) assigned the address of the first element of the array and then it reassigned the address of the first element of the string literal. And address of this first element of the string literal is returned from the function. The local variable (that is the function parameter) is destroyed after exiting the function.

These operations do not influence on the original array itself. All the time you dealt with local variable s within the function.

If you want that the string literal would be copied in the original array you have to use standard C function `strcpy` declared in header `<string.h>`. For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

char* str( char *s )
{
    strcpy( s, "readers" );

    return s;
}
```

In this case the original array will be changed because in function `strcpy`  there is used pointer to its first element that is `s` So the string literal is copied in the area pointed to by the pointer that is in the array.

Take into account that arrays do not have the assignment operator. You may initialize an array the following way

```
char src[40] = "hello";
```

but you may not write after the array definition the following assignment statement

```
src = "hello";
```

You have to copy arrays element by element as for example for character arrays that contain strings by means of standard function `strcpy`

Answer (score 0):

Lets have a look at the code, shall we?

```
str(src);
```

Function is called with `src` as parameter. The address of the first element of the array `src` is passed to the function `str`.

```
char* str( char *src)
```

In this function, `src` is a pointer that points to the address of the first element of `src`(the array) in `main`.

```
src="readers";
```

You change the location where `src` points to and makes it point to a string literal `"readers"`. This doesn't effect the array `src` in `main`.

```
return src;
```

Returns the pointer `src`. In the code snippet you have shown, it does not have any effect.

What you actually want is

```
strcpy(src,"readers");
```

instead of

```
src="readers";
```

The former copies the string `"readers"` to `src` and its subsequent bytes and this changes the contents of the array `src` in `main`.
The latter makes the pointer `src` point to a new string literal `"readers"`.